# i want to stop javascript countdown timer with onclick event

Tags: javascript

i need help, i make a javascript function for countdown timer and here is code :

```
<script>

function start_minute() {
let startingMinutes = 20;


let time = startingMinutes * 60;

  const countDownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

  setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

  function updateCountdown() {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;

    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    countDownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes} : ${seconds}`;
    if (time > 0) {
    time--; 
    } else {
      countDownEl.innerHTML = `IT'S OVER !`
    }
    
  }
}    
}
```

The clearIntervall wont work directly in an input on click
i need to put stopfunction in this for example

Comment: what do you mean bye _The clearIntervall wont work directly in an input on click_ ?

Comment: i tried it and it wont stop the timer

Comment: Could you provide your example

Comment: <button
                            class="btn btn-warning"
                            type="button"
                            onclick="clearIntervall(start_minutes)";
                        >
                            stop
                        </button>

Comment: I implemented an example using your `start_minte` function in the answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: `clearIntervall(start_minutes)` is invalid syntax: you have two `l`s at the end of the function name. Most likely, that's why it didn't work. Remember, `console` is your friend. Heck, it's better than a friend: It tells you what you did wrong when you need it most. Not many friends do that :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let intervalId = null;

function start_minute() {
  let startingMinutes = 20;
  let time = startingMinutes * 60;
  const countDownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

  intervalId = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

  function updateCountdown() {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    countDownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes} : ${seconds}`;
    if (time > 0) {
      time--;
    } else {
      countDownEl.innerHTML = `IT'S OVER !`;
    }
  }
}

function stop_minte() {
  clearInterval(intervalId)
}

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', start_minute);
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', stop_minte);
```

```html
<div id="countdown">time</div>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
```